# Twilio Access Memory Variable in Say Action

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Is there a simple way to access a memory variable inside an Autopilot Task's Say Action like

[image: Say Action]

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't do that in the Autopilot JSON because the JSON is static. In order to make it "dynamic" and input a memory variable, you can do that in a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) that you point your Autopilot task at.

The JSON to point at a Twilio Function would be something like:

```json
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "redirect": {
                "uri": "https://your-twilio-function-path.twil.io/-whatever-your-path-is"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Twilio Function would contain JavaScript like this (you need `JSON.parse` to pull out objects saved with the [Remember](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/remember) Action which are placed at the top-level of the Memory object):

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let actions = [];
    let say = {};
    let memory = JSON.parse(event.Memory);

    say = {
      "say": `Hi ${memory.name}...`
    }
    actions.push(say);
    let respObj = {
        "actions": actions
    };
    callback(null, respObj);    
};
```

Of course, alternatively, you could use

```js
say = {
      "say": "Hi " + memory.name
}
```

Again, because your bot needs to use data from the current conversation context in the dialogue, this is a dynamic task/dynamically-generated Action. You need a Task to respond with dynamic Actions using the [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect) Action and Twilio Functions or your own endpoint. Using the Program Task window as you call it would be a static task does not use data from the context of the current conversation with the user in its dialogue.

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Thank you! The concatenation ( ... + memory.name ) works, however the inline-approach ($memory.name) does not...
I have screenshots but can't add them in a comment.

Comment: nvm... I did'nt see that one shall use `` instead of '' on strings using the inline method. Tricky one :)